# How to include non-api methods in custom build in ol3?

Tags: openlayers-3, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I need to use a method that is not marked as `@api` in OpenLayers 3, i.e. it is not exported in the default minimized build that comes with releases of OpenLayers 3. The method in question is: `getTileCoordExtent`, of the `ol.tilegrid.TileGrid` class.

I tried to add `"ol.tilegrid.TileGrid#getTileCoordExtent"` in the build json configuration, as suggested in the [configuration documentation](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/tree/master/tasks#build-configuration-files), but I got the following error:

```
ERR! No matching symbol found: ol.tilegrid.TileGrid#getTileCoordExtent
```

Does that mean that methods that are not marked as `@api` can't be exported ?  Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do other than editing the code and add the `@api` myself ?

Comment: FYI, a PR has just been merged in OL3 to have this very method included in the minimized build, thus fixing the issue I'm having.  It doesn't answer the question though, so I'm still curious about it. See: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4283

Comment: The `exports` section allow to export exportable methods of a class (method with `@api` tags).

Answer (score 0):

To borrow Andreas Hocevar's response:

> The exports are determined by tasks/generate-exports.js reading symbols from build/info,json. If you want custom symbols, you can add them to the `symbols` object in info.json, e.g.

```
{
  "symbols": [
    {
      "name": "ol.tilegrid.TileGrid#getTileCoordExtent",
    }
  ]
}
```

> Of course you should not be doing that, unless you are aware that you have no guarantee that what you add this way will be stable.

Original answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/HwWRoJF0eRU/MYvEa6-aAwAJ